# Create vue.js global function

Tags: vue.js

I strated creating a small application using **vue.js** and i would like to create a **function** that i can use in my application without re-writing the code each time, in each component.

This is my **app.js** code right now :

```
require('./bootstrap')


import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueProgressBar from 'vue-progressbar';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

Comment: That's the code you want to be in your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can create a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) then import it wherever you want to.

So let's say you got a method that you want to use it anywhere in your code. You have to create it like this:

```js
// mixins/mixin.js
export default {
  methods: {
    myFunction() {
      // your function
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can simply import it in your other files like `app.js` like this:

```js
// app.js
import mixin from '~/mixins/mixin';

export default {
   mixins: [mixin],
   created: function() {
    this.myFunction();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom function by targeting the Vue prototype object.

```
Vue.prototype.customFunction = () => {
  // your function logic
};
```

You could then call it within your components by with the `this` keyword.

```
this.customFunction();
```